# Inserting multiple rows with one single query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I was able to insert two rows by the following query. What should I do to insert more rows into it?

```
insert into friend_name(
     friend_id, 
     first_name, 
     middle_name, 
     last_name)
select  
     3,
     'rich',
     'mond',
     'hill' 
from dual
union all
select 
     4,
     'monunica',
     'bellu',
     'cia' 
from dual
```

Comment: Add another `union all`

Comment: thanks is there any other way to do it more efficiently

Comment: @kiranavula Not really if you are hard coding all the values you are inserting. If you have actual data that's already existing in another table is very simple to do

Comment: Will Oracle allow multiples of the format `insert into t (c1,c2) values (v1,v2), (v3,v4),...` ? This would at least preclude the `select ... from dual;` requirement.

Comment: @SlimsGhost it does not work in the oracle its like the code i mentioned above you need to add union all every time as you go on

Answer (score 5):

You can try this as well:

```
insert all
    into demo_table values (1, 'One', 'X' )
    into demo_table values (2, 'Two', 'Y' )
    into demo_table values (3, 'Three', 'Z' )
select * from dual;
```

@kiranavula..Incase you need to insert records only to few column of the table then use below:

***Inserting record to only 1 column of the table.***

```
insert all
    into demo_table(a) values ('One')
    into demo_table(a) values ('Two')
    into demo_table(a) values ('Three')
select * from dual;
```

Comment: wow. i have never ever seen `insert all` used that way - neat!

Comment: @SlimsGhost This is the oracle way to do it

Comment: @XING can you please explain the select statement with dual

Comment: @kiranavula..What is your doubt...!!! This is one of the way we can use insert statements.

Comment: @XING what if we want to insert data to few columns not all of them it does not work how can i do insertion without union

Comment: @kiranavula..it works but you need to mention the columns names as well. See the example.